# undefined method `model_name' for #<Set: {}>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, nomethoderror

Despite some similar issues here on SO I cannot for the life of me fix this error. I've set the form up the same way I've done my other forms in the same app. I'm just trying to build a simple basic workout log. I've never run across this error before previously and would like a few other eyes to spot what might be obvious

I have a partial in my sets folder called _form.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @set do |f| %>
<%=f.text_field :number %>
<%=f.text_field :weight %>
<%=f.text_field :reps %>
<%=f.submit "Enter Set" %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb (seems to be rendering fine)

```
<div class="create-sets">
  <%= render 'sets/form' %>
</div>
```

Sets Controller

```
class SetsController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @set = Set.new
  end

  def create
    @set = Set.new(set_params)
      if @set.save
        flash[:notice] = "Set saved"
        redirect_to @set
      else
        redirect_to @set
      end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end 



  private

  def set_params
    params.require(:set).permit(:number, :weight, :reps)
  end

end
```

This seems pretty basic and has always worked in the past so I really am at a loss here. Its as though model set isn't working for some reason. I have checked my migrations as well and made sure the DB is in existence in case I maybe forgot and that all seems to check out. Help would be appreciated here.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be a naming collision between your Set class and the ruby standard library [Set](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0//libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class. The easiest thing would be to rename your class.

Comment: Interesting, I was wondering if something like that might be the case. Let me see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Saved me a lot of time Frederick. Thanks. So that worked. Good to know for the future.